# Add setters to Control's style without breaking ControlTemplate

Tags: wpf

I have global template for the progress bar, but on one I have to bind it's color to another element's state. It seems that if I change ProgressBar's style that it looses ControlTemplate. What am I missing here?

```
<Style TargetType="ProgressBar">           
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ProgressBar">
            <Border Name="PART_Track" ... Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"  >
                <Rectangle Name="PART_Indicator" ... Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

```
<ProgressBar x:Name="PBar" Background="#d8d8d8">
<ProgressBar.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}" >
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#6CC655"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=toggleX, Mode=OneWay}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFFFF"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>-->
    </Style>
</ProgressBar.Resources>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can **inherit default style using `BasedOn`**. This way you will get all properties defined in base style including ControlTemplate:

```
<ProgressBar.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ProgressBar}}">
    ....
</ProgressBar.Resources>
```

Comment: Thanks! I did not know you can base on Type. It is great.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you should use 2 different styles:

One is the generic one.
The other is the more specific style.

**THE GENERIC:**

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">           
   <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
            <Border Name="PART_Track" ... Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"  >
                <Rectangle Name="PART_Indicator" ... Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

**THE SPECIFIC:**

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ProgressBar}}">        
   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#6CC655"/>  
   <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=toggleX, Mode=OneWay}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFFFF"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Setter>
```

This should work. The point here is to use Style inheritance correctly since one is "based on" another. This way, things shouldn't break